# python: dash live plot legends

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I recently wrote a dash program
it is refreshing number of records and refreshes or redraws the fig
the problem is when I do filter over 1 or multiple legends it won't show any of the points
but when you hover over invisible points it shows the data of the point
my code:

```
from threading import Event
import dash
from dash import dcc, Input, Output
from dash import html
from dash.dcc.Interval import Interval
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy




app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options


connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://*:*@localhost:*')

df = pd.read_sql_table('rawdata_clean', connection)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="Size", y="Price", color="Neighbourhood_Per")


index = df.index
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    
    html.H1(id='Numberofrecords', children= len(index)),
    dcc.Interval(id='up-Numberofrecords', interval=3000, n_intervals=0),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id='grph',
        
        animate=True
        
    ),

    dcc.Interval(id='up-graph', interval=3000, n_intervals=0)
  
])


@app.callback(Output('grph', 'figure'),
              Input('up-graph', 'n_intervals'))

def update_graph (n):
    
    df = pd.read_sql_table('rawdata_clean', connection)
    

    fig = px.scatter(df, x="Size", y="Price", color="Neighbourhood_Per")
    
    return fig


@app.callback(Output('Numberofrecords', 'children'),
              Input('up-Numberofrecords', 'n_intervals'))

def up_Numberofrecords (n):
    
    df = pd.read_sql_table('rawdata_clean', connection)
    index = df.index
   
    print('up_Numberofrecords')
    return len(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=9876)
```

is there any problems with this code?
i'm new to dash and plotly :D

Answer (score 0):

the problem was :

```
animate=True
```

IDK what this code does but by deleting it, it get to work